# Lock parent scroll, only allow div to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a popup div which pops up over the main page. It is `position:fixed;` and with `overflow:scroll;`.

The issue is, unless the user positions their mouse over this div, the scroll feature on touch mouses or scroll wheels, scrolls the parent window - not the div. The same applies to trackpads.

Is there a way to lock the scroll of the parent window, and set the div as the scroll through jQuery? I have found a lot of posts about the opposite - with people wishing to look the div scroll and use the parent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wont disabling the parent div's scroll work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery, here's a way you can set the body's overflow to hidden whenever the popup occurs and undo that whenever the popup goes away:

css:

```
body.popup-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and jquery:

```
$("#popup").on("show", function () {
  $("body").addClass("popup-open");
}).on("hidden", function () {
  $("body").removeClass("popup-open")
});
```